# writing this python construct in java

Tags: java, python

i found some python code io try to bring to java, but i dont know how to translate:

```
for (prev_sum, subset) in old_subsets.iteritems():
```

I would do two statementsfirst iterating keyvalues and then getting the sets?
does my "translation" covers the original meaning?

```
   //     def subset_summing_to_zero (activities):
    //        subsets = {0: []}
    //        for (activity, cost) in activities.iteritems():
    //            old_subsets = subsets
    //            subsets = {}
    //            for (prev_sum, subset) in old_subsets.iteritems():
    //                subsets[prev_sum] = subset
    //                new_sum = prev_sum + cost
    //                new_subset = subset + [activity]
    //                if 0 == new_sum:
    //                    new_subset.sort()
    //                    return new_subset
    //                else:
    //                    subsets[new_sum] = new_subset
    //        return []

  public Set<Integer> subset_summing_to_zero (Set<Integer> startvalues){
    Hashtable<Integer,Set<Integer>> subsets = new Hashtable<Integer,Set<Integer>>();
    subsets.put(0,new TreeSet<Integer>());
    for (Integer cost:startvalues){
        Hashtable<Integer,Set<Integer>> old_subsets = new Hashtable<Integer,Set<Integer>>(subsets);
        subsets.clear();
        for (Integer prev_sum:old_subsets.keySet()){
            Set<Integer> subset=subsets.get(prev_sum);
            subsets.put(prev_sum, subset);
            Integer new_sum = prev_sum+cost;
            Set<Integer> new_subset=new TreeSet<Integer>(subset); // need two steps 
            new_subset.add(cost);
            if (new_sum==0)
                    return new_subset;
            else
                subsets.put(new_sum,new_subset);            
        }
    }
    return null;

}
```

Comment: Have you run it? Does it produce all the same results as the original?

Comment: SO does not do testing. Set up equivalent tests for the python and java versions, and you will know if your new version is right. This is called parallel testing.

Comment: i have no phton and therefore i can not compare to the original one, and btw: i want to see if i use correct types and not if it somehow works

Comment: [Python is free](http://python.org/), so you can go download it and test this yourself. "SO" is StackOverflow, the site you're on, and as @andy said, it's not a place for other people to write tests for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i found some python code io try to bring to java, but i dont know how to translate:
>
> ```
> for (prev_sum, subset) in old_subsets.iteritems():
> ```

This is a loop over the entries in a dict.  The [`Map.Entry<K, V>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) interface encapsulates a key and its corresponding value the way a pair is used in Python.

The [`Set<Map.Entry<K, V>> entrySet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet%28%29) method of `Map<K, V>` allows you to iterate over entries thus:

```
for (Map.Entry<Integer, Set<Integer>> e : oldSubsets.entrySet()) {
   Integer prevSum = e.getKey();
   Set<Integer> subset = e.getValue();
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following python bit:

```
for (prev_sum, subset) in old_subsets.iteritems():
```

is just a for loop with a tuple as the item per iteration.  The following tutorial covers this:
http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/loopsandtuples.html

Comment: ther is no tuple equvalent in java, and that was my question

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Tuple.html) to find Java's Tuple interface.

In general, when you want to translate a code, you should fully understand the code you are translating, understand the algorithm and then implement it in the other language. It is not important whether the resulting code will contain the same classes or it will look similar. Important is that it should be equivalent with the initial code, which means that in all cases the results for the same input will be equal.